# Can't install .Net framework 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, windows-server-2008, .net-framework-version

I downloaded .Net framework 4.0 "dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64_SC.exe" on windows server 2008 R2, 64 bit OS and every time i run the exe file i got an error message "an error was encountered unspecified error"

first it run and give me the below:
[image]

then this error

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out, do the following:

1. in Control Panel --> internet options --> privacy --> settings --> blocking level: make it Low
2. go to this link: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=17851 and install the web installer edition of the .net framework 4.0, there is something with the windows installer that permits the stand alone version to be installed on windows server 2008 R2

Comment: 3. Set your privacy settings back to their previous level once done.

Answer (score 2):

Back again...

It appears the simple answer is you don't download stuff on Windows 2008R2. Use your workstation to download files, then copy them to the server OS.

Here's a quote from
https://serverfault.com/questions/175924/enable-downloads-on-windows-server-2008-r2 :

> *It's a pain in the rear, isn't it? That is an intentional choice on Microsoft's part. There are ways to enable downloads, but wouldn't
>   recommend it. No matter how certain you are of the reputation of the
>   website you're visiting, it's a Server OS and you shouldn't be using
>   it to browse the internet even to download patches, installers, etc.
>   Instead, use your workstation to do your downloading and then copy the
>   files up to the Server for installation.*

Comment: that's why I said this: "install the web installer edition of the .net framework 4.0, there is something with the windows installer that permits the stand alone version to be installed on windows server 2008 R2", you should upvote me :)

Comment: Don't know if I quite understood that phrase, but I upvoted you anyway (what's the web installer version? where do I get it? I just see a download button)

Comment: the web installer version is where you download a file which is about 20-30 kb and that file install the .net framework